# Instantsearch filter by custom function

Tags: algolia, instantsearch.js

Due to certain limitations I am not able to index categories and subcategories so I need a way to be able to filter a list of manually created items. It's actually a two part thing:

1: I am filtering the visible results via a toggle switch

[image: Algolia Instantsearch Toggle switch]

2: I now have a submenu (also manually created) with multiple items which need to be sortable as well.

[image]

So when I click on any item it filters. The behavior should be the same as in this [demo](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/v1/examples/e-commerce/).

This part, to be specific:

[image]

The issue I'm facing is that I don't know if this is possible at all. Yes, I looked at the obvious places but could not find anything helpful. Again, the list is created manually so I'd need some custom function to *highjack* the instantsearch results, I guess.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This should be possible, but a better way to go is find out why you can't index correctly for a hierarchical refinement list, that will be simpler. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @HaroenViaene I need a combination of a toggle filter via checkbox and the categories filter. And the toggle filter must not behave the way it does, e.g. when toggling something, the selected ones jumps to the top of the list. Plus, this whole thing needs to work with Isotope. And since Instantsearch removes the non-hits from the dom, I cannot combine this with Isotope. So, I CAN index correctly, but am restricted by the functionality it needs at the end.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with clearly what's missing right now? I'm a little confused on your status

Comment: @HaroenViaene I hope codepen is also ok. https://codepen.io/mrmooky/pen/wpqLjb Some images are missing and the toggles in front of the categories are not visible, yet functional (click 30px white space in front of "Fachbereiche" for example). When you click on either "Fachbereiche" or "Zentren" a submenu opens, thats the part I am talking about.

Comment: But this works right?

Comment: @HaroenViaene Everything works fine, the codepen just looks at bit weird. The only thing missing are the subcategories – to get back to my first question.

Comment: @HaroenViaene Is there no way to trigger a search from a function?

Comment: search.helper.search()